# Subtitle's Time Editor with Regular Expressions

Tags: c#

I have a subtitle in my string

```
string subtitle = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(srt_text);
```

`srt_text` is a byte array. I am converting it to string as you can see. `subtitle` starts and finish with

```
Starts:
1
00:00:40,152 --> 00:00:43,614
Out west there was this fella,

2
00:00:43,697 --> 00:00:45,824
fella I want to tell you about,

Finish:
1631
01:52:17,016 --> 01:52:20,019
Catch ya later on
down the trail.

1632
01:52:20,102 --> 01:52:24,440
Say, friend, you got any more
of that good Sarsaparilla?
```

Now I want to take times and put them into array. I tried

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = rgx.Match(subtitle);
```

I am thinking I can just find times but didn't put into array. 
Assume 'times' is my string array. I want to array output like that

```
    times[0] = "00:00:40,152"
    times[1] = "00:00:43,614"
    ...
    times[n-1] = "01:52:20,102"
    times[n] = "01:52:24,440"
```

It have to keep going when subtitle is finish. All times might be in.

I am open for your advise. How can I do this? I am new probably have a lot of mistakes. I apoligize. Hope you can understand and help me.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for helping. Sorry for being bad. My first time

Comment: No you were not bad at all. just unaware. Hope the solution provided might help. Have a look @Enes

Comment: To be more clear your input is `"00:00:40,152 --> 00:00:43,614"` and you need `times[1]` and `times[2]` as mentioned in the question right? Or is the complete section of 1 , 2 in the question part of your input

Comment: Also doesn't this `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)` work for you? Since where ever you are getting the time format from will obviously be time itself.. rather than something like `99:99:99`. Can you confirm me

Comment: @Enes yep.. understood.. gave you my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Regular Expressions**

---

You can do this with Regex with multiple matches using `Regex.Matches`

The regex used is

```
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)
```

- `\d` select digits
- `{2}` count of repeatition
- `+` one or many repeatitions
- `: and ,` are plain characters without meaning.

Here is the syntax.

```
var matchList = Regex.Matches(subtitle, @"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+)",RegexOptions.Multiline);
var times = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

With this your `times` variable will be filled with all the time substrings.

Below is the result screenshot.
[image]

Also note: The `RegexOptions.Multiline` part is optional in this scenario.

Comment: This is what i am looking for. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Probably this might help you get the times from the string you have.

```
string subtitle = @"1
00:00:40,152 --> 00:00:43,614
Out west there was this fella,

2
00:00:43,697 --> 00:00:45,824
fella I want to tell you about,";
List<string> timestrings = new List<string>();
List<string> splittedtimestrings = new List<string>();
List<string> splittedstring = subtitle.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).ToList();
foreach(string st in splittedstring)
{
    if(st.Contains("00"))
    {
        timestrings.Add(st);
    }
}

foreach(string s in timestrings)
{
    string[] foundstr =  s.Split(new string[] { " --> " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    splittedtimestrings.Add(foundstr[0]);
    splittedtimestrings.Add(foundstr[1]);
}
```

I have tried splitting the string to get the time string instead of Regex. Because I think Regex should be used to processes text based on pattern matches rather than on comparing and matching literal text.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am trying to understand so your 'foundstr' is my looking array?

Comment: Yes but `splittedtimestrings` will contain all the four strings. and you can access it like `splittedtimestrings[0]` and `splittedtimestrings[1]`

Comment: @Enes I have attached the screenshot for better understanding

Comment: I am taking error when i am trying to write in richtextbox to splittedtimestrings[0] . it says 'your array, out of the array limit'

Comment: Thanks for help. This is getting error because probably my bad knowledge. Thanks again your help and patience.